# Kotlin Safe Pairwise iteration

Tags: kotlin, functional-programming

I just started out with Kotlin and for practice I want to read some stuff from the program arguments pairwise.

Input to the program is as follows
Alice 10 Bob 20 ...

I have a current version which is reasonably working by chunking the input and iterating pairwise

```
for((name, age)  in args.asIterable().chunked(2))
```

However, if I pass an uneven number of arguments, the last chunked list contains only a single element and the assignment fail with IndexOutOfBoundsException.

I could make this work by adding a filter on the chunked list that throws away the last list if it is not of the correct size:

```
 for((name, age)  in args.asIterable().chunked(2).filter { it -> it.size==2 })
```

However, I have some issues with this

- I have the length of the list specified twice
- With the filter it looks a lot less readable and elegant
- The filter has to run through the whole list but only the last sublist is relevant

Is the a good solution to get chunking to return only full chunks or a safe and elegant way to read only full sub lists?

Comment: As an aside, you can drop the `it ->`, as `it` is the default name for the single parameter of a one-parameter lambda.

Comment: Still not used to letting the compiler do all the work. ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`windowed`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/windowed.html). The third argument determines whether to pass partial windows, and it is false by default so you can just leave it out.

```
for((name, age) in args.asSequence().windowed(2, 2))
```